# R/httr - errors when adding a progress bar for json request

Tags: json, r, httr

When I make a json POST request I am trying to incorporate a progress bar to monitor progress. However,  I only see the progress bar when the task has completed (it shows up at 100%) so that's not very useful...

I also get the following warnings:

```
> response <- POST(url,config=progress(),body=data2)
  |==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================| 100%
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
  progress callback must return boolean
2: In curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
  progress callback must return boolean
3: In curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
  progress callback must return boolean
etc.
```

I found [this conversation about httr](https://github.com/jeroenooms/curl/issues/30) on github which seems to imply the problem has been solved, but I'm still getting the warnings. Any ideas how I can make this progress bar work? Thanks!

Per a comment below I tried
devtools:install_github("hadley/httr")

And got the following error:

```
Reloading installed httr
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/.../R/win-library/3.2/httr/R/httr.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
> response <- POST(url,config=progress(),body=data2)
Error: could not find function "POST"
> library(httr)
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users.../R/win-library/3.2/httr/R/httr.rdb' is corrupt
```

And when I tried calling library(httr),

```
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘httr’.
```

Comment: did you `install_github("jeroenooms/httr@progress")`. It's unlikely that the fix is in CRAN yet.

Comment: It's been merged into the Hadley master so you can do `devtools::install_github("hadley/httr")`

Comment: I tried those but now I get more errors.editing the post to include. thanks for responding!

Comment: I switched back to old version because I was also getting same error as yours.

Comment: @user227710 how do i do that? will "progress" still work? thanks for responding

Comment: I wanted new version not for progress bar but for compatibility with new version of `rvest`. Old version of `httr` (and `rvest`) depends on `XML` whereas new version of `httr` (and `rvest`) depends on `xml2`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I did try that install_github but then I got the errors I posted above. (Similar errors for that and install_github("hadley/httr"). Any ideas what could be causing these? Thank you for responding